# Invoke a browser for a URL based attachment

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I need to invoke the native/default browser on the device when an attachment is URL based.  Currently I get a blank app page with the word done.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you mean is that in the response for your adapter procedure's request, there is a string which is a URL.

You do not mention the structure of said response, though...

Either way, theoretically then in your client-side code where the response is handled you you can open it using [Cordova InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)

1. To open it "inside the app": `window.open(the-value-from-your-response-object, '_blank', 'location=yes');`
2. To open it using the system browser: `window.open(the-value-from-your-response-object, "_system");`